# How fix unknown error while read, update Xlsx file with Phpspreadsheet and send as PHP output?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I trying to make action on HTTP request to generate some Xlsx file.
At start is need to read template spreadsheet, add some data to it and send it as response.
But PHPSpreadsheet fall with unknown reason.

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('test.xlsx');
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
ob_end_clean();
$writer->save('php://output');
exit(0);
```

But this code doesn't give a file at browser and fall with unknown error. Response at console looks like:

[image]

Spreadsheet file just newly created with only filled A1 cell:

[image]

But if I just change 1 row to create new Spreadsheet, it works fine.

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

// $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('test.xlsx');
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,1,'testV');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
// same code next
```

I Have:

- PHP: 7.3
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet: 1.8.2

**How to correctly open exist file and send it to HTTP response?**

**Update**

like propose [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), after enabling errors print I've got spreadsheet with error:
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41943040 bytes) in ...vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php on line 1371`

**Is it possible to say Phpspreadsheet handle only filled rows, not all?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: Hi, @ADyson. No, it only print error but doesn't describe how to open, update and send Spreadsheet file at reposnse

Comment: Well if you know what the error is then you can start to debug why it isn't working. That's your starting point. We can't help you without knowing why it's crashing, any more than you can.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So your PHP script is running out of allocated memory. Is `test.xlsx` a very large file? Your PHP settings allow a single script to use up to 134MB of RAM, according to the error message.

Comment: @ADyson, no. Like I showed at screenshot, it have only 1 cell filled. But in some reason,  phpspreadsheet tries to handle whole sheet (1048576 rows and AMJ columns).

Comment: And you're 100% sure its size on disk is not larger for some reason? It is strange then. Maybe you have to raise a bug with the phpspreadsheet project, if you are also sure there is nothing else in your PHP script which could account for this. I'm not sure there is much we can do here, unless someone who helps to maintain that project happens to find your question. On the other hand, I would be very surprised if such an obvious bug existed in a widely-used library like that. Are you using the latest version of phpspreadsheet?